# Не удалось установить SSL соединение: сервер использует шифр RC4, который считается небезопасным

Tags: c#, ssl, xnet

Пишу софт для одного сайта, использую xNet.

Но у меня как в браузере, так и через приложение, не удается попасть на страницу.
Хотя бывает, что пускает, что через браузер, что через софт

В браузере выдает такую ошибку ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH с сообщением

> Невозможно установить безопасное соединение, поскольку сайт использует устаревший протокол или набор шифров. Скорее всего, сервер использует шифр RC4, который считается небезопасным.

В приложении:

> + InnerException  {"Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение."}    System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}
>   Message "Не удалось установить SSL-соединение с HTTP-сервером 'сервер'."    string

Пробовал строку:

```
req.SslCertificateValidatorCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyError) => true;
```

не помогает.

Comment: Если есть возможность обратиться к серверу из линукса (например из виртуалки) можно посмотреть насколько устойчиво соединение, если подключаться через `openssl s_client` Если возникнут проблемы, скорее всего вы получите более информативный результат, чем от браузера.

Comment: @tutankhamun, OpenSSL изначально разрабатывался под Windows, и позже был портирован под другие операционные систем. Он и сейчас более чем стабильно работает под Windows. Можно просто скачать и запустить инсталлятор с официального сайта.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Спасибо за информацию. Не знал, что он родом из Windows. Думал, что его из среды *никсов портировали